# Fetch running total per item for a list of items in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My neo4j relationships look something like....

```
(city:City{name:'city_name'}) -[:HAS_CLUB]-> (c:Club {name:"ClubA"})
-[:Has_Member]-> (p:Person{ name:"XYZ", joinDate:'date_ in_datetime_format' })
```

so for one city, I am trying to fetch running total per Club for every club related to city. Something like...

```
Table A
/    day     club_A   club_B   club_C   
1.   date_1     2       3       3     
2.   date_2     3       5       3        
3.   date_3     4       7       6
```

So if you look at club_A column, 2 members have joinDate as date1 so total members which belong to club_A at date1 are 2. On date_2 1 more member got added to club_A. So on date_2 total number of members that belong to club_A are 3 (i.e. 2+1). Same goes for date_3 and club_B.

But if you look at club_C, on date_1 only 3 members got added but on date_2 there was no addition in club_C, so on date_2 the member's count doesn't increase and remains 3 on date_2. On date_3 3 members were added to club_C so total members belonging to club_C by the end of date_3 was 6 (i.e. 3+3).

How should I approach this to get day and club_Names as columns and get a running total of members for every club for every joinDate as shown in table A.

Comment: I can get the result in two columns like  | date_1 | [{"item":"clubA","count":2},{"item":"clubB","count":3},{"item":"clubC","count": 3}] | but not 4 columns. Clubs can be more than 3 and there is no concept of "PIVOT" in neo4j so it is not recommended to "hardcode" the column names.

Comment: @jose_bacoy how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

As per conversation, below will do a frequency count on the number of members per club per date.

I am using an APOC (awesome procedure) so ensure that you installed it. https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/installation/

```
MATCH path = (city:City {name:"city_name"})-[:Has_Club]->(club:Club)-[:Has_Member]->(p:Person) 
WITH  p.joinDate as jd, apoc.coll.frequencies(collect(club.name)) as clubs
RETURN jd, clubs order by jd
```

Sample result:

```
╒════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"jd"        │"clubs"                                                               │
╞════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"2022-11-04"│[{"item":"ABC2","count":3},{"item":"ABC1","count":2},{"item":"ABC3","c│
│            │ount":3}]                                                             │
├────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"2022-11-05"│[{"item":"ABC2","count":2},{"item":"ABC1","count":1}]     │
│            │                                                                      │
├────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"2022-11-06"│[{"item":"ABC2","count":4},{"item":"ABC1","count":2},{"item":"ABC3","c│
│            │ount":3}]                                                             │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: hey thanks for this. I want to implement reduce method to get running total for dates in this table. Do you have any idea how  to approach it?